# "compile" vs. "compiling" vs. "compilation"

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-difference

From *Nginx HTTP Server*:

> Again, problems might occur at **compile time.**

The phrase "compile time" confuses me because "compile" is a verb; It sounds ungrammatical to me.

The author also uses "compilation" for the same process.

> If the **compilation** process was successful, you are ready for...

So I have two questions:

(1) Is "compile time" grammatical?

(2) Are these three phrases valid and interchangeable?

> compile time
>
> compiling time
>
> compilation time

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the phrase **at compile time** is absolutely grammatical. If something happens at compile time, it happens during the compilation process. It's actually a fixed expression and that *at* is very important because it's part of the expression. The only thing that might possibly be wrong with it is the fact that it's missing a hyphen between *compile* and *time*: *at compile-time*. You will see both versions used in technical literature. Though I prefer the one with a hyphen because grammatically it looks less confusing. If you keep reading your computer books, you will soon find out about the existence of its cousin phrase **at run-time** which means *during the time when the program is running*.

*compile-time* and *run-time* can also be used as adjectives. The most common phrasings are *compile-time errors* and *run-time errors*. Compile-time errors happen at compile-time (during the compilation process) and run-time errors happen at run-time (when the program is actually running).

Although the phrases *compiling time* and *compilation time* by themselves might be considered valid expressions in a slightly different context, *at compiling-time* and *at compilation-time* are basically non-phrases. Thus, it's a moot point to discuss them. *at compile time* is the one you want to stick with.

Comment: I agree with everything in this answer, but it's worth mentioning that this is not a pattern that one should extrapolate too far. If something happened while I was buying something at the store I definitely would never say that it happened "at buy time". You should treat "compile time" as a technical term and not imagine that there's some general "at X time" rule that it's a case of.

Answer (score 0):

'Compile' in this sense refers to the moment when a piece of written software language is run through a process called a 'compiler' which transforms it into final written, usable code. A bit like baking a cake.

'Compile-time' is the time at which this happens. It should or could be hyphenated.

Compiling time and compilation time are not used in this special context, as another answerer has explained.

The activity is spoken of usually only in terms of 'to compile'.

You could say 'my program is still compiling'. 'It's still compiling'.

You wouldn't say 'my compilation has finished' though. You'd probably say 'my compile has finished'.